# Export Datadog Monitor Alerts Weekly

Tags: datadog

Is there a way to easily generate reports of alerts from certain monitors in Datadog, on a weekly or biweekly basis?

Context: At the moment, these alerts go to a Slack channel. Folks have to scroll through the channel to see all the issues and prioritize investigations (during sprint planning).  I am trying to make it easy for sprint planners to pull up the alerts report.

I found only a couple related things after googling:

1. Datadog has a CSV with 6 months of alerts, that you can curl to download. I guess I could curl, diff with prior week's csv and filter for interesting monitors. But does not seem like the best solution. https://docs.datadoghq.com/monitors/faq/how-can-i-export-alert-history/?tab=us
2. An old article about Monitor Trends Report which I can't find in the app. https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/monitor-alert-status/

Comment: I'm also looking for something like Monitor Trends Report

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the user account properties, you can find a section "Email me the following Reports"
[image]

After activation, I got an email with a link

https://app.datadoghq.com/report/monitor

Looks like what you're looking for