# Is there a way to export all Datadog Monitors, Alerts and Dashboards?

Tags: terraform, export, devops, datadog

So far what I got when researching about that question was summarised here ([Export Datadog Monitor Alerts Weekly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66001758/export-datadog-monitor-alerts-weekly)) and here (https://docs.datadoghq.com/monitors/faq/how-can-i-export-alert-history/#pagetitle)

My actual challenge is to find a way to mass convert several monitors, alerts and dashboards to Terraform scripts.  The reason for that is that the actual DevOps infrastructure and process have already in place an automation that reads from a GIT full of Terraform scripts and once it gets a new Pull Request it imports to the Datadog environment the Monitor, Alert or Dashboard that was in the approved pull request.

Is there a way to export all Datadog Monitors, Alerts and Dashboards into a set of JSON files?

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into Terraformer? https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/guide/how-to-import-datadog-resources-into-terraform/#terraformer

There is also a Datadog github repo called miscellany that has some importer and exporter scripts for dd resources. The one most related to what you're talking about is probably Dogmover. https://github.com/DataDog/Miscellany/tree/master/Dogmover

Comment: The link to Terraformer no longer works. Is it the same as https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer/blob/master/docs/datadog.md?

Comment: Whoops looks like the link changed: https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/guide/how-to-import-datadog-resources-into-terraform/#terraformer 

That is the correct repo, and I'll update my answer

Comment: Dogmover has been deprecated in favour of https://github.com/DataDog/datadog-sync-cli